# jQuery proxy functions and events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the following jquery plugin I have made:

```
(function($) {

    //
    // Constructor.
    //

    var Tb = function(element, options) {
        var self = this;

        this.options = options;
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.$input = $(element).find('.tb-input');
        this.$label = $(element).find('.tb-label');

        this.$element
            .proxy('click', this.$input.click)
            .proxy('val', this.$input.val);
    };

    Tb.prototype = {
        constructor: Tb
    };

  //
    // jQuery plugin.
    //

    $.fn.tb = function(option) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this)
                , data = $this.data('tb')
                , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.tb.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option);

            if (!data) {
                $this.data('tb', (data = new Tb(this, options)));
            }

            if (typeof(option) == 'string') {
                data[option]();
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.tb.defaults = {};
    $.fn.tb.Constructor = Tb;

})(window.jQuery);
```

HTML (demo)

```
<div id="tb-user-name" class="tb">
    <label class="tb-label">This is the placeholder</label>
    <input type="text" class="tb-input" />
</div>
```

javascript init:

```
$('#tb-user-name').tb();
```

So basically If I do this:

```
$('#tb-user-name').val(); // Should return the value of the input not the "container".
$('#tb-user-name').focus(); // Should focus on the input, not the "container"
```

But my code is not working, how can I do this? I have tried "on" but that doesnt work either, does work on focus with a little work around but "val" is not an event but a function.

***UPDATE (Working but hacky)***

http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/WSdmL/3/

Thanks for @teddybeard for this solution, this is however not the best way because this is kinda hacky, and since on EVERY key event the val event gets triggered, I am looking for an alternative, if anyone can help me with that that would be awesome.

Comment: i'm not going to read through your plugin to try and figure out what it's supposed to be doing, or what "is not working" means. you need to add more information if you expect useful answers.

Comment: @onlineracoon are you getting any errors?

Comment: @mattytommo no but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/WSdmL/3/

What you are trying to do is override the default `focus()` and `val()` behavior of jQuery when used on a specific element. Below, I've overridden the `val()` and `focus()` functions to have special behavior when called by an element with class `.tb`:

```
(function($) {
    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(value) {
        var self = this;
        if (this.hasClass('tb')) self = this.find('.tb-input').first();
        if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
            return originalVal.call(self);
        } else {
            return originalVal.call(self, value);
        }
    };
    var originalFocus = $.fn.focus;
    $.fn.focus = function(value) {
        var self = this;
        if (this.hasClass('tb')) self = this.find('.tb-input').first();
        if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
            return originalFocus.call(self);
        } else {
            return originalFocus.call(self, value);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It worked, but is there not another way this is kinda hacky since for every $(obj).focus() and $(obj).click we are now doing a check if they have the class (which btw can be replaced with this.data('tb'))

Comment: I've updated my answer with a cleaner version of your answer, thanks for your contribution, it works now, I will mark your answer tomorrow but I leave it open for today (if you agree) and see if someone has a better alternative.